# how can I store different value in different ArrayList in android

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I'm working with string value like this String result `"aa,bb,cc,dd,ee"`.

And already split it into `aa bb cc dd ee` with

```
qrList = result.getContents().toString().split("\\,");
List<String> resultToString= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(qrList));
```

Then I create four ArrayLists.

```
 ArrayList<String> strA = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList<String> strB = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList<String> strCD = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList<String> strE = new ArrayList();
```

When I use this code below to store string into each new `ArrayList`.

```
for(int count=0; count<resultToString.size(); count++){
    //separate string to array list
    if(count%5==0){
        strA.add(resultToString.get(count));
    }else if(count%5==1){
        strB.add(resultToString.get(count));
    }else if(count%5==2||count%5==3){
        strCD.add(resultToString.get(count));
    }else if(count==4){
        strE.add(resultToString.get(count));
    }
```

The correct result would be

- strA stored aa
- strB stored bb
- strCD stored cc and dd
- strE stored ee

It doesn't work because I only get the index value at `0` (strA stored aa).
What should I do to improve my code?

Comment: It would be great if you [format your code first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44433768/edit)

Comment: Do you split work fine? I tried it manually like "aa,bb,cc,dd,ee".toString().split("\\,"); and then you code works fine.

Comment: What you said is not possible. `count==4` must be true for your given input

Comment: To motis10,the split method works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulus operator describes the remainder of your equation.  Let us show and explain an example:

As explained [in this documentation](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-mod.html), performing modulus between two values will only show you the remainder value.  For e.g. `8 % 3 == 2` because 8 divided by 3 leaves a remainder of 2.

The reason your code is not showing your desired results is due to the usage of your modulus operator.  Regarding improving your code, I can tell that all you wanted is to use the Array List index so as to add the string from the `resultToString`
Array List.

Therefore I would modify your loop in the following manner:

```
for(int count=0; count < resultToString.size(); count++) {
  //separate string to array list
  if (count == 0){
     strA.add(resultToString.get(count));
  } else if (count == 1){
     strB.add(resultToString.get(count));
  } else if (count == 2 || count == 3){
     strCD.add(resultToString.get(count));
  } else if (count == 4){
     strE.add(resultToString.get(count));
  }
}
```

An alternative is to loop directly on the resulting `String[]` and use that relative counter in the for loop for e.g.

```
String[] qrList = results.getContent().toString().split("\\,");

for(int count = 0; count < qrList.length; count++) {
  //each index represents the split string e.g
  // [0] == "aa"
  // [1] == "bb"
  // [2] == "cc"
  // [3] == "dd"
  // [4] == "ee"
  if (count == 0){
     strA.add(qrList[count]);
  } else if (count == 1){
     strB.add(qrList[count]);
  } else if (count == 2 || count == 3){
     strCD.add(qrList[count]);
  } else if (count == 4){
     strE.add(qrList[count]);
  }
}
```

Comment: To Koshux,When I use your code to test, it can't store any value in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`startsWith`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) and add appropriate values to list

```
    for(int count=0; count<resultToString.size(); count++){
        //separate string to array list
        String s = resultToString.get(count);

        if(s.startsWith("a")){
            strA.add(s);
        }else if(s.startsWith("b")){
            strB.add(s);
        }else if(s.startsWith("c")||s.startsWith("d")){
            strCD.add(s);
        }else if(s.startsWith("e")){
            strE.add(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of giving an alternate solution please explain why his code isn't working.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim by OP `What should I do to improve my code`

Comment: I think the strings are arbitrary

Comment: @earthw0rmjim i couldn't find anything wrong so i went for testing and nothing wrong again , it must be something else wrong somewhere , though i suggested a bit clear approached